# $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff \phi$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a hard time proving the following statement
$$A \in M_{n \times n}(K) \ \text{is diagonalizable} \iff \phi: K^n \to K^n \ \text{given by} \ M(\phi)_{st} = A \ \text{is diagonalizable}$$
even though intuitively this should be relatively straightforward ($st$ denotes the standard basis).

I know the following are true:

1)$$A \in M_{n \times n}(K) \ \text{is diagonalizable over} \ K \iff \exists \ C \in M_{n \times n}(K) \ \text{s.t.} \ C \ \text{is invertible and} \ C^{-1}AC \ \text{is diagonal}$$

2)
$$\phi: V \to V \ \text{is diagonalizable} \iff \left(\exists \ \mathcal{A}=\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n \} \ \text{s.t.} \ \mathcal{A} \ \text{is a basis of} \ V \ \text{and consists of eigenvectors of} \ \phi \ \right)$$
RHS of 2) can also be rewritten as $M(\phi)_{\mathcal{A}} \ \text{is diagonal}$. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can say something more specific about the columns of the matrix $C$ which diagonalizes $A$. Understanding what the columns of $C$ are, and how the matrix representation of a linear map changes under change of basis is the key to understanding this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with 2), set $C$ to be the matrix whose columns are the $\alpha_i$.  If we start with 1) let $\alpha_i$ be the columns of $C$ (and let $D$ denote the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues $\lambda_i$).  In either direction, note that
$$
C^{-1}AC = D \iff\\
AC = CD \iff \\
A \pmatrix{\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_n} = 
\pmatrix{\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots & \alpha_n} \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\lambda_2\\&&\ddots\\&&&\lambda_n} \iff\\
\pmatrix{A\alpha_1 & A{\alpha_2} & \cdots & A \alpha_n} = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 \alpha_1 & \lambda_2 \alpha_2 & \cdots & \lambda_n \alpha_n} \iff\\
A \alpha_i = \lambda \alpha_i \qquad i = 1,2,\dots,n
$$